# How many areas are there in Brodmann map?

Tags: embryology, histology

I read Wikipedia claiming 52.
I heard that this can be extended to 54.
I see there is no limit of having more areas - just better understanding of the neuroblast migration and fibroblast too, probably.
**How is this newer classification of Brodmann map done?**

Comment: Bowmann or Brodmann map?

Comment: @potterbond007 Thank you for pointing out the mistake in the body! Brodmann map. I apparently have read too much about kidneys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am no expert on the topic, but according to an [article published](ftp://ftp.psy.gla.ac.uk/pub/frank/Depression_Wagner/outros/Maxi%20Project%20new/Papers/2010%20Brodmanns%20map%20review.pdf) on the centenary of his study, it states that the microscopical structure and classification of these areas are in parallel to the evolutionary distinction between old and new cortical subdivisions. So as and when new subdivisions are deduced ([based on its function, cytoarchitecture or the structure and organisation of cells](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brodmann_area)) the map can be extended to include them. There was no upper limit to the number of divisions set in any article I read so it would be nice if you could provide some reference to where it says that the extension can be done to 54. If you are interested, you could have a look at the map published by [Constantin von Economo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constantin_von_Economo) in 1925.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you. This is just research talk where I heard people talking about more than 52 areas. I have no idea how they are doing the division. Probably, like you describe, by thinking parallel processes at some point at a particular point in time. I think the amount of these areas i.e. processes vary between different points under considerations.

Comment: @Masi basically with the advance of research, even minute differences in any part of an area currently designated due to structural differences or some new functional properties, the map can be further extended to include them as a new subdivision. Rest, I believe it is left to the discretion of the researcher as there is no definite compulsion to map new areas unless significant differences are found. That is my understanding on the subject